# How to rotate dismissible elements in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have dismissible elements and when I delete them I want them to rotate a little bit, I know about crossAxisEndOffset: 0.3 which helped me a lot, but it does not rotate an element. I did not find any information about rotation and dismissible widget.

So, I want to make a 30-degree rotation, left the bottom

```
Dismissible(
                    crossAxisEndOffset: 0.3,

                    key: UniqueKey(),
                    background: Container(color: Colors.red),
                    onDismissed: (direction) {
                      DBHelper().delete(task.id);
                    },
                    child: TaskWidget(task.name, task.title)
                  );
```

Comment: How exactly would you like to rotate? Could you provide some example or more description?

Comment: @AlexanderArendar done

Comment: @AlexanderArendar have a look here: https://blog.geekyants.com/tinder-swipe-in-flutter-7e4fc56021bc . Please note: when clicking the buttons, the animation includes also a rotation; when swiping by hand, instead, the card moves towards the top (using crossAxisEndOffset) but there's no rotation.